# Make "if" dynamic in JSViews

Tags: javascript, jsviews

I am trying to use JSViews to make a dynamic ui.  I want to have radio buttons that hide/show different parts of the ui, and have the radio button be bound to my data.

Creating and binding the radio buttons works ok, but I am stuck on the next part.  I tried using an {{if}} to show different parts of the ui based on the same value that is driving the radio buttons.  It shows the correct ui based on the initial value, but when I change the radio button, the if doesn't evaluate with the new value.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzyzt/2/) that shows what I have so far.

The part that doesn't work the way I want is

```
template += '{{if dynamic}}';
template += 'dynamic';
template += '{{else}}';
template += 'static';
template += '{{/if}}';
template += "</div>";
```

Is it even possible to do what I want with jsviews?  I am trying to get rid of a bunch of code that was handling all the clicks and hiding and showing manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems it was a simple fix.  It just isn't documented anywhere that I could find.

If I change

```
{{if dynamic}}
```

to

```
{^{if dynamic}}
```

then it magically becomes dynamic.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nzyzt/3/).

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.

Certainly it is documented (in quite a few places actually). Here are some of them:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#jsviews - see: *"And change {{if ...}} to {^{if ...}} and it too will be data-bound.*"
- http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvplaying - see: *"Any regular JsRender tag {{someTag ...}} - whether built-in or custom - can be data-linked by adding the ^: {^{someTag ...}}."*
- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/editable/tags - see: *"Data-linked tags: {^{for ...}}, {^{:...}}, etc."*